# mergeFactor usage in solr 4.0

Tags: solr, lucene

I thought mergeFactor could be think as max number of in segment, but when it set to 10, I got 16 segments after index, and merge happened when number of in segment exceed 15 and 20. I am really confused about the mean of mergeFactor.

Here is my config

```
<ramBufferSizeMB>32</ramBufferSizeMB>
<maxBufferedDocs>100000</maxBufferedDocs>
<mergeFactor>10</mergeFactor>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [Solr Wiki - SolrPerformanceFactors - Merge Factor documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#mergeFactor)

> The mergeFactor *roughly* determines the number of segments.
>   The mergeFactor value tells Lucene how many segments of equal size to build before merging them into a single segment. It can be thought of as the base of a number system.

It is not an exact number, but a guideline for how the index is managed on disk. Here is some additional good guidance on how what different settings of this value mean to the performance of your index:

> **mergeFactor Tradeoffs**
>
> High value merge factor (e.g., 25):
>
> - Pro: Generally improves indexing speed
> - Con: Less frequent merges, resulting in a collection with more index files which may slow searching
>
> Low value merge factor (e.g., 2):
>
> - Pro: Smaller number of index files, which speeds up searching.
> - Con: More segment merges slow down indexing.

You can also reference the [mergeFactor documentation on the Lucidworks site](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Configuring+solrconfig.xml#Configuringsolrconfig.xml-%7B%7BmergeFactor%7D%7D) for some more details about how the mergeFcator works and can impact your index performance. But I think the key here is this paragraph:

> If creating a new segment would cause the number of lowest-level
>   segments to exceed the mergeFactor value, then all those segments are
>   merged together to form a single large segment. Thus, if the merge
>   factor is ten, each merge results in the creation of a single segment
>   that is roughly ten times larger than each of its ten constituents.
>   When there are mergeFactor settings for these larger segments, then
>   they in turn are merged into an even larger single segment. This
>   process can continue indefinitely.

Comment: There is a awesome blog on segments merge.http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html